# Persistent Google OpenID+OAuth?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, openid

I'm working on a web app that will require somewhat frequent access to Google Data APIs, so I decided to go with the "OAuth with Federated Login (Hybrid Protocol)" method for users to log into the app. I got the http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/ working (after some tweaks for PHP 5.3 compatibility), and am able to get an Access Token. What's the next step? How do I use this access token?

It seems like I'll need to create a local session for the user to browse the rest of the app. Will this need to be completely independent of the Google login, or how would you handle that?

Relevant: this application also needs a REST API, for which I was planning to use OAuth. Any recommendation on how to tie this in with authentication for the actual app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am using the PHP LightOpenID library ([see on gitorious](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid/lightopenid/trees/master)) for that. It handles all the authentication flow for us. You don't need to bother about token and stuff.

Here the page where I display the "Login with Google" link :

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID;

$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
$openid->required = array('contact/email');
$openid->returnUrl = 'http://my-website.com/landing-login.php'
?>

<a href="<?php echo $openid->authUrl() ?>">Login with Google</a>
```

When the click on the link, a Google page will appear ask him to authenticate and/or authorize you to retrieve his email.

Then he will be redirect to the landing page `$openid->returnUrl`. The code for that page should be :

```
<?php
require_once 'openid.php';
$openid = new LightOpenID;

if ($openid->mode) {
    if ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        // User has canceled authentication
    } elseif($openid->validate()) {
        // Yeah !
        $data = $openid->getAttributes();
        $email = $data['contact/email'];
    } else {
        // The user has not logged in via Google
    }
} else {
    // The user does not come from the link of the first page
}
?>
```

If you want to retrieve more info from the user, you have to add them to `$openid->required` in the first page. For instance :

```
$openid->required = array(
  'contact/email',
  'namePerson/first',
  'namePerson/last'
);
```

will let you, if the user accepts it, to get his first and last names as well in the second page :

```
$name = $data['namePerson/first'] . " " . $data['namePerson/last'];
```

Then, for the Oauth part, you can follow the instructions of [this LightOpenID issue](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/issues/detail?id=35#c0).